# python using smaller 2D array to map with another bigger array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a smaller array as:

```
A = np.array([2013, 2014, 2015])
Aval = np.array([14, 10, 35])
```

I have another array:

```
A2 = np.array([2013, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2013, 2013, 2013])
```

I want to create A2val such that:

```
Arval = np.array([14, 10, 35, 14, 10, 35, 14, 14, 14])
```

so, I am trying to use the values in array A to map to elements of A2 and generate an extended version of A2val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to create the mapping indices and then index into `Aval` for selecting elements off it, like so -

```
Aval[np.searchsorted(A,A2)]
```

If `A` is not already sorted, we need to use the optional argument `sorter`, like so -

```
Aval[np.searchsorted(A,A2,sorter=A.argsort())]
```